# Wix - WebProject - Add a file in the installation folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web, wix

I have n wix installer for a webproject (asp.net). This installer relies on msdeploy, so my website content is wrapped up in a zip file and this file is used for installing at the target. I'd like to include a TXT in the instalation directory, but I can't add this file into the web project solution.

Any idea of how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom action to do the job for you.

try that:

```
 <CustomAction Id="ConfigCommand" Property="Cmd" Value="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe"/>
 <CustomAction Id="YourActionName" Return="check" Property="Cmd" ExeCommand="/c copy [#README.txt] [INSTALLDIR]\README.txt "  />

 <InstallExecuteSequence>
  .....
  <Custom Action="ConfigCommand" After="SomeActionBefore"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="YourActionName" After="ConfigCommand"></Custom>
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
```